# Add Custom Header Parameters to Http Header

Tags: servlets, servlet-filters

Is there any working way to add custom attributes into the Http Header in the Http Request. So far
  I have tried putting in Servlet filter response, httpRequest doesn't have a addHeader method.   I tried Phase Listener in JSF. Nothing seems to work at all. Is there any way at all?
     I use Weblogic, is there any Weblogic specific way, say some tag which can can be used to set custom header. Suggestions please.
     In short, I want custom attributes in request of Http Header.

Is there any way I do something like below which is available for IIS server

```
<system.webServer> 
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <clear />
            <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=EmulateIE7" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Why cant you write using Filters?

Comment: The functional requirement is not clear. HTTP request parameters are completely different from HTTP headers, so your question is confusing. Further it's not clear if you're talking about HTTP request headers or HTTP response headers.

Comment: @RameshPVK : I want the http Headers in the request. And request doesn't have a addHeader Method. Request Wrapper doesn't actually puts value into the header. It just retrieves it from other sources when you call the getHeader method.

Answer (score 0):

Request headers are sent by the client who is invoking the Servlet/JSP, That is why `Servlet Spec does not allow you to add any headers to the Request`. If you want to set any custom attributes to the request, `the only way to do is using HttpServletRequest.setAttribute() method.`

Comment: I need a custom Header not Request Attribute, like say User-Agent header value, I require X-MY_HEADER into the Http Header.

Comment: You cannot. that is what i have mentioned in my answer. 'Servlet Spec does not allow you to add any headers to the Request'

Comment: Well, If you notice SSO interfaces like WebSeal or SiteMinder adds custom header values of the request apart from the usual set of Headers. Can we not do the same ???

Comment: No, it does not make sense to add header at all? what is the setting header / attribtue? tell me your use case?

Comment: Well, I have to add **X-UA-Compatible** header. This is for a JSF Application which is being ported to IE8 browser.

Comment: Ok now i understood. Then , Wrap the request and override getHeader() method, which will provide X-UA-Compatible header in addition to the request header. Please let me know if this helped you.